# What does just "on" mean as a response to "where would it take me"?

Tags: harry-potter, language-explanation

In *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2* (2011), Dumbledore and Harry met at Limbo:

> Dumbledore: We're in King's Cross, you say? I think, if you so
> desired, you'd be able to board a train.
>
> Harry: And where would it take me?
>
> Dumbledore: (*CHUCKLES*) **On**.

What does just "on" mean here?

Comment: And, I'd like to point out, Dumbledore and this "post death experience" are meant to be enigmatic, as many afterlife-expostulating scenes are.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Adding a bit of context, Harry died by Voldemort's hand, and awoke in a state of [Limbo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limbo), in a place that resembled King's Cross Station:

> In 1998, during the Battle of Hogwarts, Harry Potter allowed himself to be struck with a Killing Curse by Lord Voldemort, and he entered a Limbo state in which his spirit met with the spirit of Albus Dumbledore, at a location that Harry identified as King's Cross Station. The station was, in the unconscious mind of Harry, clean and empty except for something that looked like a small, naked child, curled on the ground, with skin that was raw and rough, as though it had been flayed, which lay under a seat. Dumbledore then revealed to Harry that the form represented a small part of Voldemort, destroyed when he "killed" Harry and thus annihilated the part of his soul which he had unwittingly implanted in him.

— [Harry Potter Fandom page on King's Cross Station](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/King%27s_Cross_Station#1990s)

Here, "on" is short for "[onward](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onwards)", that the train will take Harry into the afterlife, into the "next great adventure" of death.

> Definition of onward (Entry 1 of 2)
> : toward or at a point lying ahead in space or time : FORWARD